# Firebase Lab Test apk file results

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have tested the apk file in Firebase Test Lab  and received the following results:

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
Process: com.photobangkok.dimmi, PID: 22806
java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Crash
    at com.photobangkok.dimmi.MainActivity$a.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
...
```

what does java:6597 mean?
Can someone help me to figure out how to find the offending line in my source code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)`

The error message contains a representation of the java call stack at the time the exception occured. Looking at the above line, for example, it is telling you that the code was executing within java package `android.view.View` in the method `performClick` at line number 6597 in the file `View.java`.